# CSS: Changing child color when hover over parent

Tags: html, css

I want to change hyperlink color when hover over specific class (subject-panel) , currently hyperlink's color is just changing when hover over itself.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="subject-panel">
                    <p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'books',
                        'action'     => 'customers'
                    ),
                    'default',
                    true) ?>">  users
                    </a>
                </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.subject-panel{background-color:#EFEFEF;box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); height:30px; text-align: center;}
.subject-panel a:hover {color: white;}
```

Comment: `.subject-panel:hover a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color should change while hover `subject-panel` wrapper

1) `subject-panel:hover` - On hover event

2) `subject-panel:hover a` - On hover of subject-panel find `<a>` tag inside

3) `subject-panel:hover a:{ color: red;}` - Applied style for child selected

**[know more](http://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `:hover` on `.subject-panel` itself so that if you hover over that element `a`'s color would be changed like below:

```
.subject-panel:hover a,.subject-pannel a:hover {color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

just update your css like below

**CSS**

```
.subject-panel a:hover, .subject-panel:hover a{
    color: red;
}
```